# How do I drop multiple duplicate records, but keep the first one based on timestamp?

Tags: mysql

I have a script that is gathering what music we play online. sometimes we get multiple values of close the the same thing, but the timestamp is different. I am not sure how I can locate duplicates in mysql if the timestamp is slightly different. example below.

| id | ts | artist | song | peformances |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19567 | 2023-05-23 16:21:45 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 430 |
| 19568 | 2023-05-23 16:22:48 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 434 |
| 19569 | 2023-05-23 16:23:27 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 438 |
| 19570 | 2023-05-23 16:23:32 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 438 |
| 19571 | 2023-05-23 16:23:34 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 438 |
| 19572 | 2023-05-23 16:23:51 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 439 |
| 19573 | 2023-05-23 16:23:59 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 442 |
| 19574 | 2023-05-23 16:24:10 | Mercy Me | Then Christ Came | 441 |

I do have a library table that has the artist, song and duration values. I wonder if I could use the duration field to eliminate anything inside that window with the artist and song title? Ultimately, I want to drop additional records that are duplicates, and run this as maintenance every night. As always, thanks community for the help.

Comment: I guess you need to decide WHICH of the duplicates is the TRUE one, and if it doesn't matter, you can use a select * from table limit 1 to only get one result, granted this is just to find the unique one you like, then you could delete from table where the string matches but the key is NOT the one you selected .. does that make sense?  Find one to keep, then delete all other matches that do not have that key .. an even faster way is do it in a few clicks using the free program MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Note when I say Primary Key in your case you called it ID but likely that is an Auto-increment Unique field?  So that number will never duplicate, allowing you to pick which of them you want from that list.

Comment: I feel like you need to provide more details in your question. What parameters define a duplicate?  What does performances represent? How would a duration column in another table help and what is its schema?

Comment: @UncleCarl it seems quite clear to me, when a song is played, multiple entries are added to the DB. Only the one with the earliest timestamp is to be kept. The duration is useful because all entries that have a timestamp included between the earliest and earliest+duration are duplicates. The hardest part in SQL to me is how to determin which is the first, the rest will just be a `BETWEEN` clause with `DATE_ADD`

Comment: start by defining "duplicate"; everything with the same artist and song?  artist, song, and performances?  same artist, song, and performance and some range of timestamp difference?

Comment: Did you have any constraint on `artist`/`song` columns? How did you get all this duplicates?

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the help. I appreciate it. I am going to start working through some of the suggestions. In our environment, we run a web stream server, and I wrote a python script to check for the current song and scrape how many listeners (performances) there are. Sometimes, we have to switch to our backup encoder and it creates a "blank", which the script dumps, and restarts, which is why it generates multiple values sometimes. Ideally, I want to fix the error handling in it help, but I also want this as a "fail safe", so I can run it nightly.

Comment: @Kaddath has it correct. The first occurrence would be what is True, and then multiple entries within the duration time on the "library" would be a duplicate (except the first value). I think I need the actual log of our automation to use as our cross reference so we can use as a "true" reference to base my query on. That would get me the true first value, yes?

Comment: I just had a thought on the error handling for the python script, ( I know it isn't in this question so feel free to disregard, but I left my rubber duck at home today,) I can query the last entry in MySQL to see if they are the same, if they are, disregard the entry. I think I just need to figure out where to put that in that script. Hopefully a two prong approach will rid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I drop multiple duplicate records, but keep the first one based on timestamp?

I.e. you want to delete rows if the row with lower timestamp exists.

```
DELETE t1
FROM tablename AS t1
JOIN tablename AS t2 USING (artist, song) -- assume that these columns defines duplicates
WHERE t1.timestamp_column > t2.timestamp_column
```

`WHERE` won't allow to delete the row with the least timestamp, because there is no lower timestamp. All another rows will be deleted.